# I/O benchmarking: writing large files vs using fsync on smaller files

Tags: c, caching, io

I am using an I/O benchmark for measuring the I/O performance on a system. The benchmark writes a file to disk using various i/o primitives (writes, pwrite, mmap, etc.) and reports the performance. The documentation of this benchmark states that to avoid unrealistic results seen due to effects of caching, one should write a file that is atleast equal to the size of main memory on a system.

My question is, if you use `fsync` in your program, shouldn't it circumvent effects of caching as it flushes unwritten i/o buffers to disk? I am asking this because our system has 64GB main memory and writing 64GB files every time for our experiments takes a long time. If I could write a smaller file like 4G or 8G, the tests would go faster.

I used fsync in a sample program and verified that caching effects are generally not seen when fsync is used, but I am curious to know what people have to say, and why the benchmark writers did not do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are forgetting that while 'fsync' will write all records from the cache to disk it will not remove this data from the cache, so your read performance benchmarks will still reflect the improvements due to buffering.

Comment: @James: You should probably respond with that as a new answer, it's more correct.

Comment: @James Will read performance improve if non-buffered I/O is selected with 'direct=1' option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; `fsync()` (or even `fdatasync()`) shouldn't return until the data has been written out to disk.

The benchmark you describe does not sound particularly sophisticated.